# Is there any array function by which I can get the expected result?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any array function by which I can get the expected result?

### My array

```
$a = array(
[0] => array( 'id' => 6 ),
[1] => array( 'id' => 5 ),
[2] => array( 'id' => 8 ),
[3] => array( 'id' => 4 ),
);
```

### Result Expected

```
$a = array(
[0] => 6,
[1] => 5 ,
[2] => 8 ,
[3] => 4,
);
```

I can do that using foreach loop. But I am searching for a array function ..

Comment: If you felt so inclined, you could use `array_walk` to produce a new array.

Comment: As of PHP 5.5.0 the [`array_column()`](http://php.net/array_column) function will give you your expected result easily.

Comment: @salathe, You should post that as an answer, it's a good one.

Comment: @salathe Thanks. but my php version is 5.3.25

Comment: @LukeMills , some people have the integrity to recognize, that a single-line answers should no be posted by 20k+ users.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly, yes, there is a function `array_walk()`:

```
array_walk($a, function (&$value) {
    $value = $value['id'];
});
```

But a foreach loop is probably more efficient in this case:

```
foreach ($a as &$value) {
    $value = $value['id'];
}
```

A foreach loop has very little overheads compared to an array_walk, which has to create and destroy a function call stack on each invokation of the callback function.

Note that in each case, $value is passed by reference (using the & operator). This means that the array is changed in place, no copying of the array is necessary.

Comment: @DevlshOne, I didn't see you're comment until after I posted my answer, I promise :)

Comment: Note that the array is never *copied* as such, even without passing by reference. PHP is more intelligent than to needlessly duplicate data.

Answer (score 1):

This will give the expected output in `$a`

```
$a = array_map('current', $a);
```

#### Reference

- [`array_map` — Applies the callback to the elements of the given arrays](http://php.net/array_map)
- [`current` — Return the current element in an array](http://php.net/current)

Comment: @tere Seriously?! Answering a question is now repwhoring? Especially when the rest of the answers are dominated by IMO not so great answers? There's simply nothing else to say about this one liner.

Comment: @deceze How would one go about repwhoring without posting answers, that's my question to you.

Comment: Just as a side note: While I agree that the question is poor and bears the question why the OP needs a different solution, no one provided a dupe or closevote, so I guess answering this is fine. However, a one liner is almost *never* a good answer and 20k+ users should be role models when it comes to answering. Adding a link to the manual and adding a small explanation doesn't take much effort.

Comment: @Gordon Hint taken. Much more eloquently expressed. :) But seriously, sometimes I have a hard time saying anything more about self explanatory one liners...

Answer (score 0):

Foreach seems more efficient in the situation.

```
$resultArray = array();
foreach ($a as $key => $value){
    $resultArray[] = $value['id'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can use array_walk,

```
$a = array(
0 => array( 'id' => 6 ),
1 => array( 'id' => 5 ),
2 => array( 'id' => 8 ),
3 => array( 'id' => 4 ),
);


array_walk($a, function ($ar, $val) {
       global $a;
       $a[$val] = $ar['id'];
    }
);
```

The resulting array will produce

```
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 4 )
```

For php versions 5.5 and up the following command should work.

```
$a = array_column($a, 'id');
```